# Preventing code duplication for functions with signatures differing only by lvalue/rvalue semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, move, code-duplication

I need to implement functions (operators to be specific) with signatures looking like this:

```
friend MyClass operator+(MyClass&& lhs, MyClass& rhs);
friend MyClass operator+(MyClass&& lhs, MyClass&& rhs);
friend MyClass operator-(MyClass&& lhs, MyClass& rhs);
friend MyClass operator-(MyClass&& lhs, MyClass&& rhs);    

MyClass& operator+=(MyClass& other);
MyClass& operator+=(MyClass&& other);
MyClass& operator-=(MyClass& other);
MyClass& operator-=(MyClass&& other);
```

These are 8 functions, but morally there are only two implementations, as all + and - operations are basically the same. I'd like to avoid writing the same thing 4 times only to cater to different rvalue signatures. Is there a canonical way to do this? I came up with something like this:

```
MyClass& operator+=(MyClass&& other) {
    ... // Actual implentation details.
    return *this;
}

MyClass& operator+=(MyClass& other) {
    return *this += std::move(other);
}

MyClass operator+(MyClass&& lhs, MyClass&& rhs) {
    auto myClass = MyClass();   // Copy ctor is deleted.
    myClass += rhs;

    return myClass;
}

MyClass operator+(MyClass&& lhs, MyClass& rhs) {
    return std::move(lhs) + std::move(rhs);
}

// Similar implementations for operator- and operator-=.
```

This seems to work, but since I'm not really confident in the world of move semantics I'm unsure whether I wrote something horrible and there's a much easier and cleaner way to do this. For example, what is the overhead of using `std::move`? Are there side-effects I'm unaware of?

Comment: Your implementation of `operator+=(MyClass& other)` violates [the Principle of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). Few would expect that `a += b;` renders `b` unusable. That's assuming `operator+=(MyClass&& other)` actually takes advantage of rvalue semantics and moves data from `other` - if it doesn't, then why do you go to all that trouble, rather than just having one overload that takes `const MyClass&`?

Comment: Does your `operator+=` *actually* mutate the `rhs`? That's... an unpleasant thought.

Comment: Your implementation of `operator+(MyClass&& lhs, MyClass&& rhs)` never even uses `lhs`. Is it supposed to be this way?

Comment: Overhead of `std::move` is exactly zero. It doesn't actually move anything - it's simply a convenient way to write a cast to rvalue reference. Whatever the resulting rvalue reference is passed to is what's doing the moving.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, @StoryTeller
`operator+=` does actually mutate the `rhs`. The reason to go through all this trouble is to satisfy the requirement that these statements actually compile: `MyClass c1, c2; c1 += c2; c1 += MyClass(... /*args*/)`;

Comment: So as far as I understood - the fact the two implementations are exactly the same is just a coincidence, because if I wanted I could utilize move semantics in the rvalue signature operators and then they would differ significantly?

Comment: Yes. The whole point of taking rvalue reference is to steal some data structure it manages from inside of it, as opposed to cloning it. If you don't plan to do that, then it doesn't really matter whether the argument is an lvalue or rvalue. In that case, just take `const T&` - it accepts both kinds.

Comment: Yeah, but `const` is `const`, and as I said, `rhs` is actually mutated in the process.

Comment: Ah, I read it as "does not mutate". Well then, you have highly unusual requirements, so it's expected that you have to write highly unusual code to meet them. I would suggest not to overload operators, but to provide named methods whose names convey the semantics. Again, the future reader and maintainer of your code will not expect that `a += b` has the side effect of ruining `b` (and it's not clear to me that `a + b` does to `a`).